# Adding Three subplots on Matplotlib 1 one on top pf the other

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to make a graphing interface with 3 different graphs one on top of the other.
i have so far

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
```

the top one

```
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
```

the second one

```
plt.subplot(2,1,3)
```

supposed to be the third one but keeps giving error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the first number in subplot is the number of rows of plots (the second number is the number of columns). So the first number should be 3 every time you call plt.subplot.

Comment: @IramShahed if this solved your problem, you can accept it

Comment: oh yeah forgot that :)